# Swift - Bringing UIPageViewController controls to front

Tags: swift, xcode6, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble bringing the dotted UIPageControls to the front after I filled out the whole screen.

Here's my current code:

```
    import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    //This outlet wasn't originally there. Added a UIPageControl as an attempt to solve my issue
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?
    var pageTitles : Array<String> = ["Orc", "Elven", "Undead"]
    var pageImages : Array<String> = ["Plain_Orc.png", "Plain_Elf.png", "Plain_Undead.png"]
    var currentIndex : Int = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self

        let startingViewController: PageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!
        let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        self.pageViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 37);
        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
        //self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

        //replacing addSubview from insane-36
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, belowSubview: self.pageControl!)

        self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        //Bring pagecontrols to front? (DOsESN'T WORK)
        //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.pageViewController!.view)

        //attempt to fix above code from insane-36
        view.bringSubviewToFront(self.pageControl!)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(self.pageViewController!.view)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex

        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index--

        println("Decreasing Index: \(String(index))")

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex

        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        println("Increasing Index: \(String(index))")

        if (index == self.pageTitles.count) {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> PageContentViewController?
    {
        if self.pageTitles.count == 0 || index >= self.pageTitles.count
        {
            return nil
        }

        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as PageContentViewController
        pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index]
        pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index]
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        self.currentIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return self.pageTitles.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }


}
```

I thought the line that brings the pageViewController view to front would fix my issue, but it doesn't work. Hopefully someone can give me a push in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use any one of the following method to send the **UIPageViewController**'s view to the back of the **UIPageControl**,

1. Instead of using **addSubview:** to add **UIPageViewController's**
   view, use

> ```
>    view.insertSubview(pageViewController.view, belowSubview:self.pageControl)
> ```

2. Use **bringSubviewToFront:** method,

> ```
>    view.bringSubviewToFront(self.pageControl) // after you have added the UIPageViewController's view
> ```

3. Use **sendSubviewToBack:** method,

> ```
>     view.sendSubviewToBack(self.pageViewController.view)
> ```

Comment: Tried editing with your code.

Sadly I don't have a UIPageControl in my viewController.

I tried adding one with an IBOutlet but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm updating my original post with the edited code so you can see.

And thank you so much for helping out.